# iOS: Retrieve Phone Number from Incoming Call

Tags: ios, ios5, sms, phone-call

From what I can tell, this is not possible, but I wanted to ask in case there were any potential workarounds that have cropped up recently.

Ultimately, I want to programmatically send a message (of some kind) to whoever is calling (while my app is active).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Neither is programmatically sending a text message (assuming you mean sending a message from the user's phone).